# Div's don't center with iPad media queries

Tags: html, css, center, media

On my website: http://luukschroder.nl/test/test.html# I'm inserting media queries to display content properly on other mobile devices.

On the main site are two div's (#wrap and #scrollbar) displayed next to each other, and I want to display them centered in a row on smaller mobile devices (i.e. iPads)

This is what is in the stylesheet:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
font-family: 'RobotoMono Regular';
src: url('RobotoMono-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
html *
{
font-size: 10pt !important;
color: #000 !important;
font-family: "RobotoMono Regular" !important;   
}
#scrollbar {
position:absolute;
right: 100;
width: 512px;
text-align: center;
}
#wrap {
float: left;
position: absolute;
left : 120px;
top: 40px;
}
</style>

etc.etc.
```

And this is what is in the media query css sized for iPads:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
font-family: 'RobotoMono Regular';
src: url('RobotoMono-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
html *
{
font-size: 10pt !important;
color: #000 !important;
font-family: "RobotoMono Regular" !important;
}
#scrollbar {
position:relative;
top:-150px;
width: 100%;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
}
#wrap { 
width:100%;
position:relative;
top:-100px;
padding: 0px;
float:none;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
}
</style>
```

This is the result i get: http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//luukschroder.nl/test/test.html&w=768&h=1024&a=22

I just can't seem to figure out what i am doing wrong...

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: The website looks that bad on desktop computers too. Try making #red wider.

Comment: It looks like the pictures are stacked vertically at larger (desktop) resolutions as well. Can you better describe what you're hoping for? Or, better yet, provide a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: You have a lot of errors in the HTML. Does the problem persist if you  correct all of them?

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasn't entirely clear. I want the images to stack vertically, but when viewed on an iPad I want to show the div that contains the images (#scrollbar) centered below the text (#wrap)(this works now because of Yandy_Viera's suggestion), instead of on the right. 
And yes I should definitely try to take out all the errors, I'll try to see if that makes things work better. 

Thank you!

Comment: I've taken out the CSS errors and that did the trick!
This tutorial really helped me: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to overwrite `left` and `rigt` on `#wrap` and `#scrollbar` respectively on your medias because that style affect them with `position: relative` like this:

```
#wrap{
    left: auto;
}

#scrollbar{
    right: auto;
}
```

Anyway fix the others errors in the html as suggested Mr Lister.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for #scrollbar! For some weird reason #wrap still doesn't center entirely... Maybe I should try to fix all the errors... any tips on how to do that? Dreamweaver doesn't show any errors...

Comment: I'm glad to helps, on the other hand you have inconsistent css, e.g `float: left;` and `position: absolute;`, the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties are used to position the absolute element, in medias you set `position: relative;` and `top: -150px` you could set `position: static;` so you would not have to worry about `top`, anyway check this out  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/30-html-best-practices-for-beginners--net-4957 , http://modernweb.com/2013/08/12/writing-better-css/?utm_source=html5weekly&utm_medium=email , http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/writing-your-best-code/

Comment: Great! I'll work my way through that. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your media query: for both #scrollbar and #wrap try changing `display: block` to `display: inline-block`. and then adding `float: left`

Hope that helps!